# How to concatenate values of parameter when strings

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation

This calls me to  concatenate two strings that are not yet declared they are still in parameter

I have tried to give the parameter values in string form and have console log the strings to become arguments in console.log(string + string2)

```js
function concatenateTwoStrings(string1, string2) {

  var string1 = "dance"
  var string2 = "party"
}
console.log(string1 + string2)
```

expected result is danceparty
    actual result is syntax error.

Comment: Did you try `console.log(string1+string2)` inside the function as well?

Comment: You should consider naming your variables and parameters differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript has function scoping which means that `string1` and `string2` are only accessible from within the `concatenateTwoStrings` function.

Where you have the `console.log` statement, the variables are **out of scope**.

Additionally, you probably want to pass the strings to the function instead of defining them inside of the function.

Maybe what you want to do is put the `console.log` inside of the function and call the function with `"dance"` and `"party"` as parameters:

```js
function concatenateTwoStrings(string1, string2) {
  console.log(string1 + string2)
}

concatenateTwoStrings("dance", "party")
```

Or you may want to return the concatenated string and then `console.log` result:

```js
function concatenateTwoStrings(string1, string2) {
  return string1 + string2;
}

console.log(concatenateTwoStrings("dance", "party"))
```

---

**Further Resources:**

- A good description of *scope* from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your variables outside of the function if you want them passed as a parameters. You also have to pass those arguments into the function and invoke the function.

```
var string1 = "dance"
var string2 = "party"

function concatenateTwoStrings(string1, string2) {
  return string1 + string2;
}
console.log(concatenateTwoStrings(string1, string2))
```